# Best way to detect Vanishing/Exploding gradient in Pytorch via Tensorboard

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

I suspect my Pytorch model has vanishing gradients. I know I can track the gradients of each layer and record them with `writer.add_scalar` or `writer.add_histogram`. However, with a model with a relatively large number of layers, having all these histograms and graphs on the TensorBoard log becomes a bit of a nuisance. I'm not saying it doesn't work, it's just a bit inconvenient to have different graphs and histograms for each layer and scroll through them.

I'm looking for a graph where the `y` axis (vertical) represents the gradient value (mean of gradient of a specific layer), the `x` axis (horizontal) shows the layer number (e.g. the value at `x=1` is the gradient value for 1st layer), and the `z` axis (depth) is the epoch number.

This would look like a histogram, but of course, it would be essentially different from a histogram since the `x` axis does not represent beans. One can write a dirty code that would create a histogram where instead of beans there would be layer numbers, something like (this is a pseudo-code, obviously):

```
fake_distribution = []
for i, layer in enumerate(model.layers):
   fake_distribution += [i for j in range(int(layer.grad.mean()))]
writer.add_histogram('gradients', fake_distribution)
```

I was wondering if there is a better way for this.

Comment: You could look a the norm of your model's parameter gradient.

Comment: @Ivan could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Taking all parameters gradients of your model together in a single tensor, you could either compute its norm and plot that or take the maximum norm. Take a look a the implementation of [`clip_grad_norm_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/clip_grad.html#clip_grad_norm_) for inspiration on how you could handle the gradients.

Comment: @Ivan Wouldn't I need to see the gradients of each layer separately to see if they are vanishing? The max norm would only give me the biggest gradient which is a single number when I take all gradients in a single tensor.

Comment: You could look at the norm of the gradient of the parameters as one tensor. Looking at each gradient would be quite unreasonable. Depending on the size of your model, for example, if you are working with thousands of parameters you will end up needing to monitor the same amount of gradients. Another idea would be to look a the gradients on a particular layer of your model....

Comment: @Ivan My model had millions of parameters, looking at them one by one is out of question, however, it has only about 16 layers. As I understand, In vanishing gradient, the gradient gets smaller and smaller as the layers get further from the output layer, so to detect vanishing gradient one would need to compare the gradients of several layers (not all the parameters in those layers, but norm max of each layer).  And that is my question how to look at the gradient of several layers, in one graph or chart.

Answer (score 5):

This is a minimal example of how you could go about evaluating the norm of a particular layer in your model. Taking a simple model for illustration purposes:

```
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 10, 5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(8000, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, 10)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(input))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return x

net = ConvNet()
net(torch.rand(5,1,28,28)).mean().backward()
```

Looking at [`clip_grad_norm_`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/utils/clip_grad.py) as reference. To measure the magnitude of the gradient on layer `conv1` you could: compute the L2-norm of the vector comprised of the L2-gradient-norms of parameters belonging to that layer. This is done with the following code:

```
parameters = net.conv1.parameters()
norm_type = 2
total_norm = torch.norm(
    torch.stack([torch.norm(p.grad.detach(), norm_type) for p in parameters]), norm_type)
```

Alternatively, you can take the maximum of maximum gradient component on that layer *i.e.* the inf-norm:

```
total_norm = torch.max(
     torch.stack([p.grad.detach().abs().max() for p in parameters]))
```

---

To log them onto your TensorBoard, you can use [`add_scalar`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html#torch.utils.tensorboard.writer.SummaryWriter.add_scalar) on your `SummaryWriter`:

```
for name, module in net.named_children():
    norm = torch.norm(
        torch.stack([torch.norm(p.grad.detach(), 2) for p in parameters]), 2)
    writer.add_scalar(f'check_info/{name}', norm, iter)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it. But my question is about logging these gradients in Tensorboard log. Your answer returns one number for each layer. But that's not the part I'm struggling with. As I explained in my question, logging all these numbers creates a mess in Tensorboard. Ideally I would like to see all these gradients (4 gradients in your example) in a single graph, not on four different graphs.